# Button click event not working in a included activity, inside another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-drawer

I have parent activity with drawerlayout, in it's xml I put dashboard layout using include tag and in xml of this dashboard layout I put 'MainActivity' using include tag again. In the xml of MainActivity there is button, for which in onclick I put some logic in MainActivity.java. Problem is button is rendering, but click is not working anyway

1. I want to write business logic for click in MainActivity.java, that button which is in xml of MainActivity.xml.
2. Button click must work in this way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide your code and your java file so that we can answer your question. Actually your question is bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, You have used <**include** tag in **ParentActivty** and you have given id as "@+id/layout_button" And also in **ChildActivity** you have given Button id as "@+id/button"

If you use "**viewbinding**" in your codebase then you can get the reference of this button by calling **binding.layoutButton.button**

Comment: Can you clear me please, is there not any way, that I do keep business logic on click of that button in java file of child activity and button click must work, because currently it is not working in a simple way, as it is indirectly inside parent activity using include tag.
If I use viewbinding, I think I will need to write code for click in parent activity java file.
I want to keep code modularization.